# Вывести часть датафрейма, соответствующую экстремальным значениям

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть график ящик с усами, который показывает по годам уровень счастья в мире. И за три последних года я увидела, что есть экстремальные значения.

Задача: вывести фрагмент **DataFrame** который соответствует этим экстремальным значениям.

Я использовала такой код:

```
df_all_years[(df_all_years['Ladder score'] < 3.2)&(df_all_years['year']>2018)]
```

НО он выводит больше информации, чем хотелось бы получить.

Идея у меня состоит в том, что бы указать значения за пределами интерквартального размаха: **q1-iqr*1.5.**

А как это сделать я не понимаю.

Использовала цикл **for** и **if**, но ничего  не получается.
([image: 'График с ящик с усами по парметру "Ladder Score" - уровень счастья'])
График ящик с усами по парметру "Ladder Score" - уровень счастья'

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Первый раз на сайте. В следующем посте не буду добавлять. Просто увидела, что сайт предоставляет такую возможность задающим вопрос, поэтому решила добавить.

Comment: добавлять картинки вам никто не запрещает. в качестве дополнительной иллюстрации. ну или когда без картинки не понять суть вопроса. в общем, прочитайте, пожалуйста, то, на что я дал ссылку выше.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я читала правила, поэтому в качестве иллюстрации показала свой график, он наглядно показывает суть вопроса

Comment: вы же понимаете, что не данные получаются из графика, а график из данных? тип вашего график абсолютно не релевантен к вопросу. а вот пример исходных данных бы пригодился.

Comment: Конечно понимаю, я задала вопрос, исходя из графика, потому что задача у меня возникала, когда увидела этот график.  Ящик с усами показывает, что для будущего кода, хорошо бы использовать теоритические знания по квантилям, моя логика мне подсказала, что быстрее обьяснить суть вопроса, это показать график. Все люди разные и думают по разному. На счет исходных данных, я пока не знаю, как на этом форуме предоставить пример своего dataframe (изображение загружать нельзя, ввиду на реакцию). Тогда в каком формате, если не сложно обьясните новичку?

Comment: Ну так вы возьмите квантили и от этого уже дальше фильтруйте: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html  Только судя по графику, вам отдельно по каждому году нужно это делать будет.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я хочу получить отдельно таблицу с четырьмя строками, которые соответсвуют точкам - экстремальных значений со столбца "ladder score". А квантили по всем годам сразу, у меня считает. Я думала условие года (с 2019 по 2020) задать в цикл вместе с формулой квантилей и вернуть строчки таблицы. Просто не знаю как.

Comment: @ElenaBabenko фильтрующий код, который Вы прислали выглядит актуальным, а какой результат он возвращает и почему он Вам не нравится?

Comment: @ElenaBabenko извините за вопрос - а Вы результаты его работы куда-то присваиваете? Из кода это не ясно, из кода видно, что результат работы этой строки никуда не сохраняется.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov мне не надо присваивать, потому что это информация мне нужна только для описания, в каких странах живут стольнесчастные люди. Выводит пять строчек, из которых мне пришлось выбирать правильные. Хотелось автоматом вывести экстремальные значения по условию не попадания в промежуток.

Comment: Приведите хотя бы часть данных в виде воспроизводимого примера: `df_all_years = pd.DataFrame({'year': ..., 'Ladder score': ...})`

Comment: @CrazyElf, добрый день. Привожу ниже код: **df_all_years = pd.concat([df_new, df_2021_new], ignore_index=True)
df_all_years.head()
df_all_years.sort_values(by =['Country name', 'year'], ascending=[True,True], inplace=True)
df_all_years.head(20)**

Comment: -0   Country name                  2098 non-null   object 
-1   Regional indicator            2098 non-null   object 
-2   year                                  2098 non-null   int64  
**3   Ladder score                    2098 non-null   float64**
-4   Logged GDP per capita   2062 non-null   float64
-5   Social support                2085 non-null   float64
-6   Healthy life expectancy  2043 non-null   float64
-7   Freedom to make life choices  2066 non-null   float64
-8   Generosity                      2009 non-null   float64
-9   Perceptions of corruption1988 non-null   float64

Comment: В комментариях нет форматирования, добавляйте это всё в вопрос, а не в комментарии. Хотя это не совсем то, что я просил, всё-равно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не хотел использовать построчный `.apply`, так как ничего, кроме синтаксиса он не улучшает по сравнению с `for`, но так ничего и не придумал.

**Решение**

C помощью .groupby, считаем края нижних усов для каждого года.
*(Комментарий: фильтрацию по годам можно добавить на любом этапе).*

С помощью построчного `.apply` создаем маску с использованием данных из предыдущего этапа и применяем ее к исходному датафрейму.

```
import random
import pandas as pd

# создадим тестовый датафрейм с нормальным распределением в колонке 'Ladder score'
dic = {
    'year': [random.randint(2017,2020) for _ in range(1000)],
    'Ladder score': [int(random.normalvariate(500, 90)) for _ in range(1000)],
    'some': [random.randint(100, 999) for _ in range(1000)]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic)

# в переменную gr получим подсчитанные нижние усы для каждого года
gr = df.groupby('year')['Ladder score'].apply(
    lambda x: x.quantile(0.25) - (x.quantile(0.75) - x.quantile(0.25)) * 1.5
)

# создадим маску
mask = df.apply(lambda x: x['Ladder score'] < gr[x['year']], axis=1)

print(df[mask])
```

Повторю, этот код вернет все аномалии по всем годам. Чтобы ограничить нужными годами, можете применить фильтр на любом этапе.

```
print(df[mask & (df['year'] > 2018)])
```

Comment: groupby + apply - самое то, я поленился решение писать, но думал в ту же сторону, это лучше чем for и вполне в духе Pandas

Comment: @CrazyElf к groupby + apply у меня нет вопросов, так как в этом случае .apply обрабатывает вектор, а вот во втором случае, когда .apply обрабатывает строки, по сути - тот же for - просто перебор строк. Я, при каких-то данных, сталкиваюсь с ситуациями когда for работает быстрее чем построчный .apply. Но формально, конечно, был соблюден pandas-style. Если Вы считаете, что построчный apply все равно лучше чем for - буду благодарен за разъяснения, возможно я что-то упускаю.

Comment: А, я тормознул. Второй `apply` - там нужно смотреть, может и так всё хорошо. А может лучше через `join` присоединить `gr` и дальше уже условие делать, я не уверен, как лучше.

Comment: @CrazyElf немного скорректирую свои претензии к apply. Сейчас провел замеры в двух вариантах. В первом варианте я сравниваю apply с for, который применен непосредственно к датафрейму. Apply выигрывает по скорости у for **0.07:0.09**, во втором варианте я конвертировал серию 'Ladder' и серию 'year' в два списка, прошелся по ним циклом и замерил время конвертации+цикл. В этом случае apply проигрывает **0.07:0.01**.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov можно упростить: `df1 = df[df['Ladder score'].lt(df.groupby('year')['Ladder score'].transform(lambda x: x.quantile(0.25) - (x.quantile(0.75) - x.quantile(0.25)) * 1.5))]`

Comment: @АлексейР Очень круто! До меня так и не дошло как избежать построчной пробежки, а у Вас тут все в канонах векторных операций. В очередной раз Вы мне открыли метод .lt :) Не чувствую себя в праве вносить такие изменения в свой ответ - это не упрощение, это совсем другой подход. Если оформите как ответ - я плюсану.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov и АлексейР. Очень красивое решение, спасибо большое еще и разложили по полочкам. Прям мечта так научиться решать такие задачи. Филигранная работа ребята.

Comment: @ElenaBabenko если ответ устраивает, будем благодарны за плюс и выбор лучшего ответа.

Comment: @АлексейР вы не могли бы порекомендовать литературу или источник, где можно доступно овладеть методологией lambda и lt?

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov  Мне оба ответа понравились. Хотела бы поставить плюсик двоим. Так можно?

Comment: @ElenaBabenko Решение АлексейР объективно лучше. Но чтобы выбрать его ответ лучшим, необходимо, чтобы он оформил свое решение как ответ, а он этого по каким-то причинам не делает. Поэтому "плюсик" можно поставить только мне кликнув на стрелку вверх слева от верха ответа и на флажок там же. Если Алексей оформит ответ, то Вы всегда сможете перенести флажок с моего ответа на его.